# PowerShell - How to put the following script together + adjust Header and Footer

Tags: powershell, scripting

Here is a sample of the script for Word Document that I am working on it at the moment 
The script changes a word in all of the files, but **** does not **** change part of the file name and Header and Footer

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
$objWord.Visible = $false

$list = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\*.*" -Include *.doc*
foreach($item in $list){
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($item.FullName,$true)

$objSelection = $objWord.Selection 
$wdFindContinue = 1
$FindText = "COMPUTER" 
$MatchCase = $False 
$MatchWholeWord = $true
$MatchWildcards = $False 
$MatchSoundsLike = $False 
$MatchAllWordForms = $False 
$Forward = $True 
$Wrap = $wdFindContinue 
$Format = $False 
$wdReplaceNone = 0 
$ReplaceWith = "DESKTOP" 
$wdFindContinue = 1 
$ReplaceAll = 2

$a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, ` 
$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,` 
$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith,$ReplaceAll) 
$objDoc.Save()
$objDoc.Close()
}
$objWord.Quit()
```

Heres the scrip to change a part of the file name :

```
PS C:\User> get-childitem | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("file1", "computer") }
```

How can I put everything together ?
Thanks

Comment: There is nothing in your word code that addresses you header footer needs. Changing the file name or part of the file name is a common practice, with examples in the help files and all over the web and on this site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887905/powershell-update-fields-in-header-and-footer-in-word, your rename command is static, but you say you are hitting multiple files. Are you say, all files, contain the word file1, and you are trying to replace the files1 with the word computer? That comes off as all files are name the same, which is not a thing.

Comment: I was wondering if theres a way to combine all of it. I do understand that the code does not address header and footer. Wondering If someone could help

Comment: @postanote  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041100/powershell-workaround-for-the-blank-header-footer-bug-when-find-and-replace-in-a                                                                                                          this is what I was talking about, but I tried to add  this code : get-childitem |foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("test", "test1") }  to change the file's name, but ended up getting an error .

Comment: See my answer for this rename effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That last code segment is outside of what you are doing in word. So, when you say combine, it's just as you are already doing:

You are not saying / showing what error you are getting form this last code segment.

When trying to rename files, you have to use the full filename, and that includes the path to that file, just as you did in the word segment.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Temp -Filter '*.txt' 

    Directory: E:\Temp

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       11/27/2018   3:51 PM              0 OriginalFileName.txt


Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Temp' -Filter '*.txt' | 
ForEach { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.FullName.Replace('Original','New')) -WhatIf }


ForEach { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.FullName.Replace('Original','New')) -WhatIf }
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: E:\Temp\OriginalFileName.txt Destination: E:\Temp\NewFileName.txt".



Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Temp' -Filter '*.txt' | 
ForEach { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.FullName.Replace('Original','New')) }



Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Temp -Filter '*.txt' 


    Directory: E:\Temp

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       11/27/2018   3:51 PM              0 NewFileName.txt


foreach($item in $list)
{
    $objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($item.FullName,$true)

    $objSelection = $objWord.Selection 
    $wdFindContinue = 1
    $FindText = "COMPUTER" 
    $MatchCase = $False 
    $MatchWholeWord = $true
    $MatchWildcards = $False 
    $MatchSoundsLike = $False 
    $MatchAllWordForms = $False 
    $Forward = $True 
    $Wrap = $wdFindContinue 
    $Format = $False 
    $wdReplaceNone = 0 
    $ReplaceWith = "DESKTOP" 
    $wdFindContinue = 1 
    $ReplaceAll = 2

    $a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, ` 
    $MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,` 
    $Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith,$ReplaceAll) 
    $objDoc.Save()
    $objDoc.Close()

    Rename-Item -Path $item.FullName -NewName ($item.FullName.Replace($item.BaseName,$FindText)) -WhatIf
}
$objWord.Quit()
```

Just remove the -WhatIf to have it run for real of course.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to run it later